# Recommendations for presenting about 35 fields for data entry

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

When the user clicks on a node in a treeview, I'd like to present the user with a way to fill-in about 35 fields. Should I use one form, tab control, etc?
Thoughts/Recommendations?

Comment: A better fit for this question might be http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Technically, you can do whatever you want.  This is more of a design question, which tend to be more opinionated (i.e. there is no one way to do it correctly).  Since the scope of the question is very vague, it would be hard for anyone to give a definitive answer.

Comment: What kind of information you need to give a recommendation/suggestions? I'm not asking for definitive or correct answer.Users are technical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the type of your users. If they are tech guys, just put everything on the table. If not, try make it as simple as you can. For starters try and put 3 or 5 fields in a "wizard" like format. Give details about how to complete the fields, put a nice next button. If you want your users to know how much they have to complete use a progress bar. If you don't want your users to know they will spend some time completing the form, don't use a progress bar, just leave it as a surprise. Tabs is totally NOT the way. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you. Users are technical.